# what happens behind an example of a reverse string program?

Tags: python

so my friend tasked me with changing a string by reversing it, obviously reversing a string gives you just the object id, i managed to find a way to do it but i dont understand what happens under the code. The part i dont get is how join() works with a reversed value, does a value when reversed get converted into a list or tuple before using the join? i didnt clarify to change the string into a list, so what part of the code carries over that change?

```
a = 'apple'
b = '1'.join(reversed(a))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what's going on when you call the `reversed` function:

```
>>> a = 'apple'
>>> reversed(a)
<reversed object at 0x000002119BDDA3E0>
```

`reversed()` isn't giving you an "object id".  The object id is what you'd get if you called `id()` on that object:

```
>>> id(reversed(a))
2274652699040
```

`reversed()` is giving you a special iterator object (which is neither a list nor a tuple) that reverses whatever you passed into it.  This object doesn't implement a nice `__repr__` method, which is why you get the default `<CLASS object at ADDRESS>` string representation if you just try to print it to the console as-is, but you can do anything with it that you can do with any other iterator.

For example, you can loop over it:

```
>>> for i in reversed(a):
...     print(i)
...
e
l
p
p
a
```

you can turn it into a `list`:

```
>>> list(reversed(a))
['e', 'l', 'p', 'p', 'a']
```

and you can pass it as an argument to `str.join`:

```
>>> ''.join(reversed(a))
'elppa'
```